# Passing Swift string to and Objective-C framework method causes loss of string

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm passing a Swift string to my Objective-C framework method which accepts an NSString. However, sometimes (not all the time, depending on the value) it doesn't get converted to an NSString.

My understanding was that that this would get down cast.

If I explicitly cast the Swift string to an NSString the framework method causes an error.

[image]

```
-(id)setField: (NSString*)nme
recordTypeName: (NSString*)recordTypeName
   parentName: (NSString*)parent
   parentEnumVal: (NSInteger)parentEnumVal
     dataType: (eFieldDataType)dataType
       dbType: (eFieldType)dbType
      enumVal: (NSInteger)enumVal;
```

Sometimes the debugger shows NSTaggedPointerString with the string correctly shown.

Also NSCFString again with the correct string.

Then _TtCs19_NSContiguousString again with the value, but this gets subsequently lost when read back later, showing a completely different class.

I would try a newer version of Xcode, but I'm using the latest. I think this must be an Xcode bug.

EDIT:

The error occurs when I later read back the field

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, Some strings aren't strings their unrelated class references. I use the setField method several times and add them all to an array. When iterating the array, some are fine and are string and others are class references. All the none strings are fine.

Comment: No I just want the string

Comment: I just can’t get the string value

Comment: I thought it would be easier to add to GitHub, line 28 https://github.com/Jules2010/SwiftObjcFx/blob/master/mcl-icloud-db/mcl-icloud-db/Classes/iCloudSchemaTable.m

Comment: Oh ok, I've added an image with the error.

Comment: If I turn on NSZombies I get [CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: I'm just passing in a plain string in swift "RecordName"

Comment: Don't suppose you can give me some key words to add to a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) NSString *name;
```

Fixed with

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *name;
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` is implicitly bridged to `NSString`, just declare a Swift string

```
let user_name = "user_name"
```

Comment: As vadian said, the thing is, that the framework method is "exported/bridged" to the Swift world as `func setField(_ name:String, recordTypeName:String /* ... */) -> AnyObject`, so in Swift it expects a Swift `String`, not a `NSString`

Comment: So I'm not sure what I need to change, seems like your saying it's fine as-is ?

Comment: Don't create an `NSString`. Replace `var user_name : NSString = NSString(string: "user_name")` with the line in the answer. A type annotation is not needed. A literal string **is** `String`

Comment: I had that to start with, I added the line with NSString to show it wasn’t an NSString being passed to my framework method.